# restart aws rds during snapshot creating

Tags: amazon-rds

Long story short, I wanted to change instance because I am out of storage,ram and cpu. Currently i am on free tier mode 1 cpu 1 gb ram 20gb storage ( and i am using now 16 gb )
The support said its easy just modify the instance type. But to safety first create snapshot before it.
So I created at least started.
[image]

My problem is that this is hanged 0% for 30 minutes now, and I cannot use my db neither. ( only select works ). And I am also sure if this snapshot creates to the same 20 Gb where the database is its will full before its even finish.

**My question is, what happens if I restart my database server? Is the snapshot gone and my database is safe ?** 
*Or what should I do? :) is it normal that the progress is updated after a long time?*

Comment: sorry my panic. The progress bar looks useles, becase after ~45 mins the snapshot suddenly finished and everything works.